# Follow me Mission TimeOut DJI SDK

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I am trying to create a custom FollowMe mission by sending a vehicle's GPS data on Android studio. i can send the vehicle coordinates,but the updateFollowingTarget gives a timeout error.I'm using mavic 2 zoom  and dji sdk v1.14 .Did someone manage to fix this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug. It always returns timeout.
Just dont care about the error and it will work.

But it speed limited to like 15km/h so dont expect to much from it.

Edited (Do you know another function that i can use to follow a vehicle's GPS signal):
Yes, it involves more programming though.

You have to use virtualstick to control the drone. This is the only way to control the drone programmatically.

I have done it here, follows a tracker app running on a phone on my head:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i3axYfIOHTY

Im working on a python api for dji. In that framework the top level code looks like below. The virtualstick calls are inside move_towards():

```
while True:
        tracker_location = api.tracker.get_location()
        drone_target_location = copy.deepcopy(tracker_location).move_to(Changeable.radius.get_value(), Changeable.bearing.get_value())
        drone_location = api.drone.get_location()
        course_to_tracker = drone_location.get_course(tracker_location)
        heading = api.drone.smooth_heading(course_to_tracker)
        drone_target_distance, drone_speed, course = api.drone.move_towards(drone_target_location, height=current_altitude, heading=heading, lowest_altitude=Changeable.lowest_altitude.get_value(), deadzone=[Changeable.dead_zone0.get_value(), Changeable.dead_zone1.get_value()], k_distance=[float(Changeable.k_dist0.get_value()), float(Changeable.k_dist1.get_value())], speed_deadzone=Changeable.speed_deadzone.get_value())
```

Comment: Thank you  for your answer.Do you know another function that i can use to follow a vehicle's GPS signal.I tried with  Custom Timeline Missions  it works but the drone just stops after each mission so i lose the speed advantage and cant keep up with the vehicle .Thanks in advance.

Comment: You welcome :-) 
I updated the answer with some python code of how I have done it and a youtube clip of how well it works. Bear in mind that virtualsticks have a max speed of 15m/s, (I found a way to get 22m/s for mavic 2, but its not easy done.)